# Pagination with query string gives error page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller is this:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'category';
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
$config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
```

When I click on 2nd page it shows an error **page not found**

Comment: post error. (From Review).

Comment: Post the URL you're directed to and the intended one.